# Can use CSS Properties as a HTML Attibutes?

Tags: html, css

Example:

```
p {
            color:blue;
            font:Arial;
            font-size:30px;
            }
```

all css properties can be a html attribute?

```
<p color="blue" font="Arial">Some Text</p>
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried...

Comment: Please clear up the question.  Are you asking if all CSS properties have a corresponding HTML tag attribute?

Comment: No, very few css props can be used as attributes. In fact, such usage is discouraged.

Comment: i mean html attribute like `width`, `height`

Answer (score 1):

CSS properties are not valid HTML attributes, but they can be set inline to an HTML element through the `style` attribute.

e.g.

```
<p style="color:blue;font:Arial;font-size:30px;"> content.....</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with the `style` attribute:

```html
<p style="color:blue;">Text</p>
```

CSS is valid within the `style` attribute's value.